# How much embedded program memory in this NXP (aka freescale) KL03 processor?

Tags: processor, nxp, freescale

Is there a way to find out how much programming memory is in an NXP (aka freescale) KL03 ARM processor?  The markings on the chip say "P03T5V" and "PSABA".

There is [this NXP package number lookup web page](http://www.nxp.com/packages).  But it does not work for the above (any?) number.

...thanks

Comment: Where did you get it from?

Comment: This is certainly written (along with the marking details) in the datasheet.

Comment: @dim I think the OP is unable to find the datasheet, as he doesn't know which part it is.

Comment: @Eugene He said KL03, which narrows the search down. But I'm looking at the datasheets right now, the problem is: the markings don't seem to be indicated.

Comment: I have the actual part.  All the letters on the part are listed in quotes in the question.  The part comes in 8KByte, 16KByte & 32KByte sizes.  These are listed in the data sheet along with the Freescale part number.  But the part numbers do not match what is engraved on the actual part.

Comment: @EugeneSh., directly from NXP.

Comment: @st2000 So how is that you don't know the part number?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good question - they were sampled parts & I'm not the person who sampled them.  I know the BOM calls for 16KByte parts.  But someone told me the sampled parts were 32KBytes.  But I'm having problems pushing the code size beyond 16K to 32K (lots of changes necessary in the SDK).  So I thought to ask here in case I was chasing ghosts.

Comment: You need to find out the PN from whoever have ordered them. There should be some order docs somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the simpler processor, the NXP KL02, you see in its chip specification that the 5 in the 1st line means 32KByte of program memory.  And if you look at a more complex processor, the NXP KL17, you see in its chip specification that the 5 in the 1st line means 32KBytes of program memory.

I appears that NXP failed to include the chip markings into its NXP KL03 processor's specification.  I think it is fair (safe?) to say that the 5 in the 1st line found on the KL03 processor part means that the processor contains 32KBytes of program memory.